# Latex Indentation

Tags: latex, indentation

I have a list which I want to indent from the section title. I have tried `\indent` and `\hspace{1cm}` without success.

Here is my code

```
\vspace{0.2in}
\section{Affiliations} 
\vspace{0.1in}
\indent The American Geophysical Union.\\
\hspace{1cm} The Seismological Society of America.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For consistent indentation of a "somewhat list-like structure", use `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\section{Affiliations}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  The American Geophysical Union.

  The Seismological Society of America.
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

However, I'd suggest a regular list-like structure like `itemize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{Affiliations}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1cm]
  \item The American Geophysical Union.
  \item The Seismological Society of America.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```